# How to make a fading effect with Core Graphics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I want to make an effect like what you see on the right side of the first cell here:

[image]

I'm guessing it's some sort of overlay view with a gradient, but I just can't figure out how it's configured with transparency. I tried making my own overlay view with a gradient and set the alpha of the colors down, but it just shows up as a gray - white gradient.

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor *gradBegin = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.8];
    UIColor *gradEnd = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.6];
    NSArray* gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                               (id)gradBegin.CGColor, 
                               (id)gradEnd.CGColor, nil];
    CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0, 1};

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)gradientColors, gradientLocations);

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height/2.0), 
                                CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height/2.0), 0);
```

What exactly is going on in this screenshot, and how can I replicate it?

Comment: Isn't it just an UIImageView with a gradient from clearColor to gray on top of the content view of the cell?

Comment: put a uiimageview over top of your other view with a png that has a gradient from white to clear.

Comment: Can I do this without UIImageView and just use a UIView with CoreGraphics?

Comment: How have you made your overlay view above, and what is its background colour?

Comment: It just comes out as a square with a light gray to dark gray gradient..no transparency really

Comment: I tried gradient with UIColor clearColor, but that just comes out black

Comment: This code works fine.  I had fading.  I quickly wrote test code.  I will show my listing in another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simple UIView class that will draw itself faded.  It is a basic UIView with the drawRect overrided:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor* gradBegin = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0];
    UIColor* gradEnd = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
    NSArray* gradColours = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    (id)gradBegin.CGColor,
                                    (id)gradBegin.CGColor,
                                    (id)gradEnd.CGColor,
                                    (id)gradEnd.CGColor, nil];
    CGFloat gradLocs[] = { 0, 0.5, 0.9, 1 };
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colourSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)gradColours, gradLocs);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, 0), 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);
}
```

This works if overlayed over your view and the view's background is white.

Answer (score 2):

While this certainly can be done with Core Graphics, it's infinitely easier to add a transparent PNG to your project with the appropriate width and 1 pixel height and then position a `UIImageView` in your table cell over the content to create this effect.

Comment: I hate PNG's :( So many different resolutions I have to render as..and if I want to make changes I have to go back and resize all the images..would be so much more convenient in CG

Comment: It minimizes the file size and can be stretched to any height. Use the scale-to-fill content mode.

Comment: Cool, well, got the PNG method to work. Wasn't too bad. If anyone comes up with a Core Graphics solution, it would be interesting to see..

Answer (score 1):

The gradient drawing code in your question looks ok, although I haven't tested it.  I suggest setting `gradBegin.alpha = 0` and `gradEnd.alpha = 1`.  Also, the last line could be simplified:

```
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, rect.origin,
    CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), rect.origin.y, 0);
```

And don't forget to `CGGradientRelease(gradient)`.

Anyway, other than that, you need to set `overlayView.opaque = NO`.

Comment: Do I generally have to release most CG stuff even if I use ARC?

Comment: Yes, unless you bridge it to a Cocoa object.